# System-wide bashrc on FreeBSD

Tags: bash, freebsd, port

On linux there's usually a global bashrc file (`/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`). On FreeBSD however bash doesn't seem to support this feature. What's the best way to add a system-wide bashrc then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `strings` and see which paths are included in the binary.

Anyway, in RHEL5 the only system-wide config file for bash is `/etc/profile` and there is no `/etc/bashrc` nor others.

Comment: Yes, `/etc/profile` is also a systemwide initialization file (same on freebsd). But it's executed for login shells, and not interactive shells. Anyway, the trick with `strings` is great!

Comment: You are correct for `/etc/profile`, but even in RHEL5 (bash 3.2.25) there is no trace of any other bash initialization file in `/etc/`.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no common startup file for interactive non-login shells for Bash on FreeBSD. You will have to add something like:

```
. /etc/bash.bashrc
```

to the beginning of each user's `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

This one had me thinking for a bit, so I checked out the bash installations I have on my solaris (9 and 10) and FreeBSD servers.  Turns out, that the only place that bash looks for bashrc is ~/.bashrc.

The thing is, this isn't just a Solaris or FreeBSD thing.  I checked the man page and the only profile stuff checked is the /etc/profile or the various files in the user's home dir.  So, the likely culprit is distro customization.  So, on the linux servers -- Centos, in this case --

From ~/.bashrc :

```
# Source global definitions
  if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
  fi
#fi was missing here
```

Comment: The default `~/.bashrc` also has a section like this on Debian 7, although `/etc/bash.bashrc` is called even if that section is left out.

Answer (score 1):

@dan-andreatta suggestion to use `strings` was helpful:

```
$ strings $(which bash) | grep profile
~/.profile
noprofile
/usr/local/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
```

We can see that for FreeBSD, you need to update and/or create `/usr/local/etc/profile` instead of modifying `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 0):

Check /usr/local/etc/ directory and link it with /etc/ if needed.

Comment: Nope, it's not there!